# Apply Gradient to Canvas and moving balls

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, gradient

Trying to apply a linear gradient to my canvas and it's moving balls but I don't know where I went wrong as nothing changes. I'm trying to have a randomly colored and random angle applied onload every time. I think the problem is in my onload function when I create the linear gradient

```
var $ = function(id) {return document.getElementById(id);};

var bounce;
var my_canvas;
var ball_array = new Array();
var linear_gradient;
var timer; //global variable to keep current timer

function randomGradient()
{
var color1 = randomColor(); //color 1
var color2 = '#FFFFFF'; //color 2
var gradient_angle = Math.round(Math.random()*360);
var random_gradient = "linear-gradient(" + gradient_angle + "deg, " + color1 + ", " + color2 + ")";
return random_gradient;
}

function ball(){
this.x=Math.random()*my_canvas.canvas.width;
this.y=Math.random()*my_canvas.canvas.height;
this.vx = (Math.random()-0.5);
this.vy = (Math.random()-0.5);
 this.color = randomGradient();
 this.radius = 12;
this.move=ball_move;
this.draw=ball_draw;
 }
 function ball_draw(){                    
 my_canvas.save();
 my_canvas.fillStyle=this.color; //****
 my_canvas.strokeStyle='black';
 my_canvas.lineWidth=2;
 my_canvas.beginPath();
my_canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius,0, 6.28, false);
 my_canvas.closePath();
 my_canvas.stroke();
 my_canvas.fill();
 my_canvas.restore();
 }

 function create_balls(){
 for(var i=0;i<75;i++){
    var temp=new ball();
    ball_array.push(temp);
 }
 }
    function resize_can(){
my_canvas.canvas.width = window.innerWidth/2;
my_canvas.canvas.height = window.innerHeight/2;
    }

    window.onload = function() {
    bounce = -1;
    my_canvas = $("myCanvas").getContext('2d');
    linear_gradient = my_canvas.createLinearGradient(0,0,window.innerWidth / 2,window.innerHeight / 2); //create linear gradient
    window.onresize = resize_can;
    resize_can(); 
    create_balls();
    timer = setInterval(going,5);
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create gradients with canvas, you can't just use a linear gradient CSS string

```
ctx.fillStyle = "linear-gradient(50%, red, blue)";  // WON'T WORK!
```

Use

```
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, width, height);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
```

On top of that gradients are relative to the origin so if you want to gradients to stay relative to the circles you need to translate the origin when you draw. In other words instead of

```
ctx.arc(x, y, ...)
```

You need

```
ctx.translate(x, y);
ctx.arc(0, 0, ...)
```

Note that I changed your code a bunch to be more modern JS for some definition of "modern". Examples, use `const` and `let` where appropriate, never use `var`, use `class`, use `requestAnimationFrame`, compute a delta time between frames and make the animation frame rate independent, use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`, use `[]` instead of `new Array`, get rid of `window.onload` (put your scripts at the end of you file or use `defer`), use `ctx` vs `my_canvas` (nothing wrong with `my_canvas` except it's not a "canvas" it's a "canvas context" or more specifically a [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

```js
const $ = function(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
};

const ctx = $("#myCanvas").getContext('2d');
const ball_array = [];

function randomColor() {
  return `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)`;
}

function randomGradient(size) {
  const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(-size, 0, size, 0);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, randomColor());
  gradient.addColorStop(1, '#FFFFFF');
  return gradient;
}

// JS style, constructors are always Capitalized
class Ball {
  constructor() {
    this.x = Math.random() * ctx.canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * ctx.canvas.height;
    this.vx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 50;
    this.vy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 50;
    this.radius = 12;
    this.color = randomGradient(this.radius);
    this.angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color; //****
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);  // because you wanted the gradient at a random angle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, 6.28, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  }

  move(deltaTime) {
    // you didn't provide this code so I made something up.
    this.x = (this.x + this.vx * deltaTime + ctx.canvas.width) % ctx.canvas.width;
    this.y = (this.y + this.vy * deltaTime + ctx.canvas.height) % ctx.canvas.height;
  }
};

let then = 0;
function going(now) {
  now *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
  const deltaTime = now - then;
  then = now;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ball_array.forEach((ball) => {
    ball.move(deltaTime);
    ball.draw();
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(going);      
}

function create_balls() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 75; i++) {
    const temp = new Ball();
    ball_array.push(temp);
  }
}

function resize_can() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2;
}

window.onresize = resize_can;
resize_can();
create_balls();

requestAnimationFrame(going);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Good but if all you want to `save()` is the transform matrix, better use directly the absolute `setTransform()` rather than saving **all** the context's properties and restoring them for every Ball. And closePath on a closed arc (i.e circle) does nothing good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill your canvas and select gradient colors.

Something like:

```
my_canvas = $("myCanvas").getContext('2d');
var linear_gradient = my_canvas.createLinearGradient(0,0,window.innerWidth / 2,window.innerHeight / 2);
linear_gradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
linear_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");

my_canvas.fillStyle = linear_gradient;
my_canvas.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
```